# Simulink block for plotting output (on Y axis) with input (on X-axis)?

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink

Time dependent signal is input to a Simulink model which give time dependent output, both are continuous functions, we can separately plot input/output signal values as a function of time but we want to plot input value with output value for a particular time. Does Simscape have block for that? please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try the `XY Graph` block? From your description I am not sure what you want, the "for a particular time" part is unclear to me.

Comment: XY graph has done the job :) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [xygraph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/xygraph.html) block allows you to input a signal for both, the x and the y axis.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question.